# AWS API Gateway CORS-header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: javascript, cors, aws-api-gateway, access-control

I am currently facing a problem regarding the access from my simple frontend to my API i created in API Gateway.
I've enabled CORS on the used ressource as shown in the picture:

[image]

Here is the code for my request:

```js
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            eMail: '',
            password: ''
        },
        methods: {

            // API CALL HERE FOR INITIAL VALUES
            init() {},

            // SIGNUP
            signUp() {
                let userData = {
                    "mail": this.eMail,
                    "password": this.password
                }

                console.log(userData);

                const request = {
                    host: 'myapi.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `***********`,
                    data: userData, // object describing the foo
                    body: JSON.stringify(userData), // aws4 looks for body; axios for data   ...path: `/Prod/foos/${foo.id}`,
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                };

                axios(request).then((response) => {
    if(!response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
                    console.log(response);
                });

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.init();
        }
    });
</script>
```

When using the script i get the following error in the firefox debugger "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing". I am yet to find a solution to this problem

Comment: Try in a different browser or after clearing your browser cache or force-reloading.

Comment: Can you attach the response generated after running the following curl command?
curl -v -X POST https://myapi.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/account --data "..." Ideally the response headers should include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. But I guess in your case the backend implementation does not return that header.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try to find some time to do it in the next couple of days.